# How does this particular Python recursion work? Why the result value becomes 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21?

Tags: python, recursion

Could you explain step by step, why the result value becomes 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21?

```
def recursion(number):
    if(number > 0):
      result = number + recursion(number - 1)
      print(result)
    else:
      result = 0
    return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
recursion(6)
```

Comment: I would recommend running it through http://www.pythontutor.com/

Comment: What about it specifically do you need help understanding? Have you walked through it using a debugger?

Comment: This is from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp     I just want to understand how it work step by step. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this function is returning the sum of consecutive numbers up to a certain value. Before you look at the code and try to understand it, you need to breakdown the problem:

Let's take some variable `sumUpTo6 = 6 + 5 + 4 .... 0` which is the sum of numbers up to 6. Then let's take another variable `sumUpTo7 = 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 ... 0` which is the sum of numbers up to 7. Notice now, that I can rewrite `sumUpTo7` as `sumUpTo7 = 7 + sumUpTo6`

Now if we replace these variables with calls to your function:

If `recursion(6)` gives me the sum of numbers up to 6,

Then `recursion(7) = 7 + recursion(6)`

And more generally speaking, `recursion(number) = number + recursion(number-1)`

But what about when we reach `recursion(0)`? Well this is called the base case, and we want `recursion(0) = 0` (because the sum of numbers up to 0 is 0).

So now let's put this all into code:

```
def recursion(number):                           # `number` here is the number we want to add up to
    if (number > 0):                             # if `number` is greater than 0, we can use the number below it to get the answer
        result = number + recursion(number-1)    # we use the logic above
        print(result)                            # show the result on the command line
    else:                                        # if `number` is not greater than 0, then it must be less than or equal to 0
        result = 0                               # in this case the sum up to number will be 0
    return result                                # pass the result up to the caller
```

**The call to `recursion(6)` will run something like this:**

1. We call `recursion(6)`
2. 6 is greater than 0. So we call `recursion(6-1)` which is `recursion(5)` and we will add 6 to this. We don't print anything yet because we wait for `recursion(5)` to finish.
3. 5 is greater than 0. So we call `recursion(4)`. Nothing printed yet.
4. 4 is greater than 0. So we call `recursion(3)`. Nothing printed yet.
5. 3 is greater than 0. So we call `recursion(2)`. Nothing printed yet.
6. 2 is greater than 0. So we call `recursion(1)`. Nothing printed yet.
7. 1 is greater than 0. So we call `recursion(0)`. Nothing printed yet.
8. 0 is not greater than 0, so we return 0. We don't print anything here
9. So for recursion `recursion(1)` we got `1 + 0` (from previous line) so we print 1 and return 1
10. For `recursion(2)` we got `2 + 1` (from previous line) so we print and return 3
11. For `recursion(3)` we got `3 + 3` so we print and return 6
12. For `recursion(4)` we got `4 + 6` so we print and return 10
13. For `recursion(5)` we got `5 + 10` so we print and return 15

... you get the idea

**I added some print statements to the code below to make it easier to understand:**

Run this with different numbers...

```
def recursion(number):
    if(number > 0):
      print("{} is greater than 0".format(number))
      print("Calling recursion({}-1)\n".format(number))
      previous_result = recursion(number - 1)
      print("recursion({}-1) gave {}".format(number, previous_result))
      result = number + previous_result
      print("returning {} + {} = {}\n".format(number, previous_result, result))
    else:
      print("Hit 0! Returning 0\n")
      result = 0
    return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results\n\n")
recursion(6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I dont understand is, why the result value became
1
3
6
10
15
21

Comment: Added an explanation!